# How to resolve this error? i am getting repeatedly this error in my project when i start apache tomcat server 6

Tags: tomcat6

How to resolve this error? I am getting repeatedly this error in my project when I start apache tomcat server 6

[image]

Please find below error and give some suggestions to rectify this

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2015-06-04 14:51:17,540 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/${GyreFxConfigFile}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
```

How to resolve this error? i am getting repeatedly this error in my project when i start apache tomcat server 6

Comment: did you get a chance to check if Spring , Tomcat and JDK are compatible with each other

Comment: The problem is everything good but we getting this prb

Comment: Thanks satya, But I checked every thing all are seems good so could u pls tell file name where we will get this type of errors

Comment: Somewhere, probably in a properties file, you have a property called GyreFxConfigFile. It looks like this is not being correctly picked up in your Tomcat environment. Try checking the properties file that contains this property really is there, and is in a location that's on the classpath.